# Entity Framework: Change table to view without updating EDMX

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, edmx, sql-view

Does entity framework care if the table mapped in the EDMX is actually a view in the database if the columns and names are the same?

I'm working on an application where the database might have to change, but we may not be able to immediately deploy an updated EDMX with the new table structure. My colleague wants to add a view for each table in the database and update the EDMX to map to views instead of tables, and use stored procedures for insert/update/delete operations. That way if we need to change the table structure we can keep the view columns and procedure parameters the same and our EDMX file won't be affected. To me it seems like overkill to have views that mirror every table just in case we want to change one of them later, so I'm looking for another solution.

One idea is to leave the EDMX mapped to tables. If the table needs to change later then the table can be renamed and a view can be created with the same name and the same columns.

I tried an experiment and created the table MyTable and mapped it in an EDMX. Then I renamed MyTable to tblMyTable and created a view named MyTable that selects all from tblMyTable.  Although the EDMX still thinks it's mapped to a table, it had no problem selecting or updating the MyTable entity. The updates aren't going to work if I have to split a table apart and join the data back together in the view, but I ought to be able to use INSTEAD OF triggers to handle that if I need to.

Are there any problems with this approach? I've never seen this done before, but from the limited testing I've done it seems like it ought to work. I know this won't work for major database changes -- if I want to completely remove a table then the application code is going to have to change. I just want to know if there is some technical reason why entity framework won't fully support this.

Comment: Did you do this in production? I am thinking about doing a similar approach.